# Access user principle with Spring Boot 2 CXF web service

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm creating a soap web service with Spring Boot 2 and the cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws package from Apache CXF.

The service is secured and I'm trying access the user principle to check for permissions.

So far I've only been able to get it working by using

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;
```

But given I'm using Spring it feels like I should be using @Autowired to match all my other injected dependencies.

Is there a way to get @Autowired to work or is using @Resource for only this dependency ok?